# reset javascript array after filtering in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular application displaying a list of names. I have a search input to filter that list.

```
<input [ngModel]="searchStr" (ngModelChange)="modelChange($event)" type="text" id="employeeName">
```

The component has this logic for modelChange(), to capture the input string and filter my names by that string. This data initially comes from a service called in ngInit(). My issue is I am overwriting my names array with a filtered down array each time a key stroke is made in the input box. How can I write this logic to reset the array back to it's original contents when the input is blank?

```
modelChange(str: string): void {
  debugger;
  this.searchStr = str;

  this.employeeList = this.employeeList.filter(emp => emp.name.includes(this.searchStr));
}
```

HTML template

```
<div *ngFor="let employee Of employeeList>
    employee.name
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the same array in modelChange, so if you want to revert to the original array (on some condition) you must keep a reference of your original array somewhere, or dont overwrite the original array at all. Maintain another array for display purpose, lets say you name it **displayArr**

Your code would update like this

```js
public displayArr:any[] = []
modelChange(str: string): void {
  debugger;
  this.searchStr = str;

  //if some search string is provided, then filter the original array
  if(str)
  {
    this.displayArr = this.employeeList.filter(emp => emp.name.includes(this.searchStr));
  }
  else //if no search string is provided then don't filter the array and return it as it is.
  {
    this.displayArr = this.employeeList;
  }
}
```

Iterate over **displayArr** and not original array to display.

```html
<div *ngFor="let employee Of displayArr">
    employee.name
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the array in an intermediate variable like so:

```
const filtered = [];
const unfiltered = [v1, v2, v3];
```

Originally copy values from `unfiltered` to `filtered`. When filtered, copy `unfiltered` filtered values to `filtered`, then revert when needed

Comment: Thanks for the help!